# Microstrategy Training metric creation

Tags: microstrategy

I am just trying to create a report with basic predictions. I have created a Freeform SQL report with the following query:

```
select Customer_ID,
Month,
Sum(Amount) as Amount from Transactions
group by customer_ID,MRR_Month_DT
```

I have declared Customer_ID,Month as Attributes and Amount as Metric. Report has no issues when running it.

Now I am just trying to add Training Metric from Insert -> New Training Metric -> Forecasting Number values (Linear Regression).  I have given Customer_ID as Independent metric and Amount as Dependent Metrics. In the next step There are two options for destination folder

```
1) First one is directory path of My report
2) Report objects
```

When I select the 1st option directory path, Predictor training metric is created on the path and am able to see the training metric in my report as well. but when I select Report Object, I am not able to see the training metric. Can somebody tell me what I did was right. Why I am not able to see the training metric if I chose report object.

P.S. I am using Microstrategy Desktop 9.4.1